# Pyscreenshot ImageGrab.grab() restarts program

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to write a program to take screenshots with python. The problem is, whenever I try to take a screenshot, the program restarts, and then takes the screenshot. This is not ideal because I want to have the user input where they want the screenshot to happen, and when the program restarts, you need to re-enter the location.
My code is:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

x1 = input("X1> ")
y1 = input("Y1> ")
x2 = input("X2> ")
y2 = input("Y2> ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        input("ENTER to take a screenshot")
        im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        im.save("Image/screenshot.png")
```

Any help is appreciated, and 
if any more information is needed, please let me know